# counter inside tikz grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

How I can insert a counter to each box of a grid? In the below example, I am just representing a 32bit float with sign, mantissa and exponent, and need to put 0-31 as a count of the 32 bit.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[mplc3!20] (0,0) rectangle (.5,.5);
        \fill[mplc0!50] (.5,0) rectangle (4.5,.5);
        \fill[mplc1!50] (4.5,0) rectangle (16.5,.5);
        \draw[step=.5, thick, fill=mplc2!20] (0,0) grid (16.5,.5);
        \node at (0.25, -.25){\textcolor{mplc3}{sign}};
        \node at (2.25,  .75){\textcolor{mplc0}{exponent}};
        \node at (10, -.25){\textcolor{mplc1}{mantissa}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \caption{Name}%
    \label{fime}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: From your description I am not exactly sure, what your intended outcome is, but probably something like `\foreach \i in {0,1,...,31}{\node at (\i+.25,.25) {\i};}` would be a starting point?

Comment: @MarkusG. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `TikZ` for this kind of schemes could be [bytefield](http://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) or [register](http://ctan.org/pkg/register).

Following example has been taken from `bytefield` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.84,1,1}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.64,1,0.71}
\definecolor{lightred}{rgb}{1,0.7,0.71}
\begin{bytefield}[bitheight=\widthof{~Sign~},
                  boxformatting={\centering\small}]{32}
    \bitheader[endianness=big]{31,23,0} \\
    \bitbox{1}[bgcolor=lightcyan]{\rotatebox{90}{Sign}} &
    \bitbox{8}[bgcolor=lightgreen]{Exponent} &
    \bitbox{23}[bgcolor=lightred]{Mantissa}
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]